# Proof that the sequence has a limit using epsilon language

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{8n-5}{3n-1}= \frac{8}{3}$$

I wrote that:
$\left|\frac{8n-5}{3n-1}-\frac{8}{3}\right| = \left|-\frac{7}{9n-3}\right|$ (since $\epsilon > \left|\frac{8n-5}{3n-1}-\frac{8}{3}\right|$).

At this point I kind of stuck, because I do not know if am I allowed to make changes while I have the absolute value( like to write $\left|-\frac{7}{9n-3}\right|<\left|\frac{-7+16}{9n}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|$ and only then say that $1/n>0$ which allows removing the absolute value symbol) or I should solve the equation as;
\begin{align*}
-\frac{7}{9n-3} & > \epsilon\\
-\frac{7}{9n-3} & < -\epsilon
\end{align*}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! Please try to typeset your mathematics with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Use `$\frac{f}{g}$` to typeset the fraction $\frac{f}{g}$, use `$\lim_{n \to \infty}$` to get the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, and use `$\epsilon$` to get $\epsilon$. (Or use `$\varepsilon$` to get $\varepsilon$.) And for goodness's sake don't use both back and forward slashes for division! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Right, so what you could do is to write:
$$\left|-\frac{7}{9n-3}\right| = \frac{7}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3n-1}$$
No harm in writing this, right? All I've done is just simplify the given expression and this doesn't cause us any problems because $3n-1 > 0$ whenever $n \geq 1$. Now, what you want is for this to be smaller than $\epsilon$. So, let's force it to be less than $\epsilon > 0$ first and then see if we can obtain some inequality involving $n$ that gives us what we want. So, we have that:
$$\frac{7}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3n-1} < \epsilon \iff \frac{1}{3n-1} < \frac{3\epsilon}{7} \iff \frac{7}{9\epsilon}+\frac{1}{3} < n$$

Now, let $N$ be any natural number such that $N > \frac{7}{9\epsilon}+\frac{1}{3}$. Then, if $n > N$, your desired inequality is satisfied by the manipulation above. Essentially, to do these kinds of problems, you need to work backwards a little bit to get the expression that you want.

Answer (score 0):

> To Prove: 
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{8n-5}{3n-1}= \frac{8}{3}$$

My approach to such limit problems that involve a fraction is to note that for $a,b,c,d > 0$, you have that

$$a < r < b, ~c < s < d \implies \frac{a}{d} < \frac{r}{s} < \frac{b}{c}.$$

That is, (for example) a lower bound on $\dfrac{r}{s}$ is computed by minimizing the numerator and maximizing the denominator.

---

For $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, you have that

$$\left|\frac{8n-5}{3n-1} - \frac{8}{3}\right| = 
\left|\frac{(24n - 15) - (24n - 8)}{9n - 3}\right| = \frac{7}{9n-3}. \tag1 $$

(1) above is consistent with the OP's (i.e. original poster's) calculation.  I should point out that the method that I described at the start of this answer is not needed here, since the numerator is a **constant**.

In order to show that the limit goes to $~\dfrac{8}{3},~$ I have to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $M \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that :

$$n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq M}} \implies \frac{7}{9n-3} < \epsilon.$$

Note that for $~n \geq 4,~$ you have that $~(9n-3) > 8n.$

You also have that for fixed $~M \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ and $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq M}},~ 8n \geq 8M.$

Therefore, for any fixed $~\epsilon > 0,~$ if $~M \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 4}},~$ such that $~\dfrac{7}{8M} < \epsilon,~$ and $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq M}},~$ then you will have that

$$\frac{7}{9n-3} < \epsilon,$$

as required.

Therefore, for any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~M \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 4}}~$ such that

$$M > \frac{7}{8\epsilon} \implies \frac{7}{8M} < \epsilon.$$